# Disabling the button after creating element dynamically

Tags: angularjs

how can i disable the button after creating element dynamically with a specific count. what i mean to say i want disable the button after creating 5 div's dynamically on a button click.... is this possible in angular js

I am giving url of fiddle  `enter code here`
HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<button ng-click="createElement()" id="btnCreateElement"ng-disabled="isDisabled">ClickToAdd</button>

<div id="target">

</div>
<button ng-click="toogleElement()">ClickToAdd</button>
<div class="tryIt" ng-if="showDiv"></div>
<div class="tryIt" id="redDiv" ng-if="!showDiv"></div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.showDiv=true;
$scope.isDisabled =false;

$scope.createElement =function(){
    var newDiv = angular.element('<div class="test"></div>');
    var newDivContainer = document.getElementById("target");
    angular.element(newDivContainer).append(newDiv);
    $scope.isDisabled =true;

}
$scope.toogleElement=function(){
    $scope.showDiv =!$scope.showDiv;
}


});
```

CSS

```
 .test{width:400px;height:30px;background:green;margin:10px 0;}
   .tryIt{width:200px;height:200px;background:#00B3E3;margin-left:50%; position:relative;}
   #target>div:nth-child(5){background:blue;}
   #redDiv{background:red;}
   #btnCreateElement{cursor:pointer;}
   #btnCreateElement:disabled{cursor:no-drop;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e61rdhtb/1/

Comment: have tried to add counter against creation of divs

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE UPDATE THE FIDDLE@JAYANT PATIL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a counter variable to track the number of click requests and disable the successive actions

Sample code

```
$scope.createElement = function() {
    if (clicks == 5) {
        $scope.isDisabled = true;
    } else {
        var newDiv = angular.element('<div class="test"></div>');
        var newDivContainer = document.getElementById("target");
        angular.element(newDivContainer).append(newDiv);
        clicks += 1;
        if (clicks == 5) {
            $scope.isDisabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gangadharjannu/64katsz6/)

Comment: Thank You soo much

Comment: I'm glad to help

Comment: but there is problem it disables the button at 6th click

Comment: You could adjust the condition accordingly

Comment: @MujtabaHussainBhat. You need to check after incrementing also. See the updated answer

Comment: sir i need your more help would you please help me that will be appriciated now i wana delete the element by clicking on cross icon how can i do that this is updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Mujtabahussain/15bd5daa/2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138532/discussion-between-mujtaba-hussain-bhat-and-gangadhar-jannu).

Comment: You can ask that as a new question so that I will answer

Comment: I posted the new question

Comment: Can you tell us the question link?

Comment: yes offcourse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903923/deleting-a-dynamically-creating-a-div-by-clicking-on-cross-icon

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain one count variable in controller.

```
$scope.count=0;
$scope.createElement =function(){
// your code
$scope.count++;
}
```

And add condition on UI so button will be disabled after 5 clicks

```
<button ng-click="createElement()" id="btnCreateElement" ng-disabled="count==5">ClickToAdd</button>
```