# Deleting a dynamically creating a div by clicking on cross icon

Tags: angularjs

How can i delete the dynamically created div that has cross icon. Clicking on cross icon div should be deleted. How can i delete the created Div

This this the link https://jsfiddle.net/Mujtabahussain/15bd5daa/3/`

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
  <button ng-click="createElement()" id="btnCreateElement" ng-disabled="isDisabled">ClickToAdd</button>

  <div id="target">

  </div>
  <button ng-click="toogleElement()">ClickToAdd</button>
  <div class="tryIt" ng-if="showDiv"></div>
  <div class="tryIt" id="redDiv" ng-if="!showDiv"></div>

</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.showDiv = true;
  $scope.isDisabled = false;
  var index = 0;
  $scope.createElement = function() {
    if (index > 5) {
      $scope.isDisabled = true;
    } else {
      var newDiv = angular.element('<div class="test"><i class="fa fa-times delIcon" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="deleteDiv(objj)"></i></div>');
      var newDivContainer = document.getElementById("target");
      angular.element(newDivContainer).append(newDiv);
      index += 1;
       if (index == 5) {
        $scope.isDisabled = true;
      }
    }
  }
  $scope.toogleElement = function() {
    $scope.showDiv = !$scope.showDiv;
  }
$scope.deleteDiv = function(objj){

}

});
```

CSS

```
 .test {
   width: 400px;
   height: 30px;
   background: green;
   margin: 10px 0;
 }

 .tryIt {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: #00B3E3;
   margin-left: 50%;
   position: relative;
 }

 #target>div:nth-child(5) {
   background: blue;
 }

 #redDiv {
   background: red;
 }

 #btnCreateElement {
   cursor: pointer;
 }

 #btnCreateElement:disabled {
   cursor: no-drop;
 }
 .delIcon{    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    cursor:pointer;}
```

Comment: Don't create elements that way. Add an element to an array in the model, and use ng-repeat to display one div per element of the array. To remove a div, remove the element from the array. If you're doing DOM manipulation in your controller, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: This is the requirement  brother i know this is the wrong but it is client 's requirement

Comment: The client doesn't care how you create the elements that appear on the page. He wants to add and remove elements on the page. Whether you do DOM manipulation or use angular correctly to achieve that goal doesn't matter to the client.

Comment: i want create elements dynamically and remove on clicking on cross icon. if i use array so i need more storage to store the details but i don't want that way. i wana create it dynamically and remove it on Dom

Comment: Then use jQuery. Angular doesn't work that way. More storage, to store a few basic objects in an array? That's a premature optimization.

Comment: Hello sir i am trying to do that way as you suggest me but i face some error can you please help me out of that i will send you the URl of fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Mujtabahussain/15bd5daa/5/ you help will be appericiated

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/pzmavad8/1/. I just left the part regarding the green closing divs, and removed the irrelevant part regarding the colored array.

Comment: Hello sir i was trying to delete the div with index but it  deletes last div. what i did just pass  index to deleteDiv() method  but it is not working. i don't know what wrong in the code...   https://jsfiddle.net/Mujtabahussain/15bd5daa/8/  actully i go through other example that is exactly same .. That example works fine but mine is not  working ..............http://plnkr.co/edit/4JbLupVFIguVd8TWVAsB?p=preview

Comment: Your code works fine. Just add some information (like a unique ID) in each object added to the array, and display that information in the template, and you'll see it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/w6f0be0v/

Comment: Thank you soo much sir  i appreciate for your help.  i got at the end that it works fine actaully what i did i had given the background color of 2nd div blue with index every time when i deleted the 2nd div it is deleted but the background -color remains blue becuase of index